# Check for solution (after BSOD) does nothing

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I have different BSODs somtimes. But "Check for solution" wizard does nothing. Note: it doesn't say it can't find solution, but it doesn't look for it at all!

After pressing "Check for solution button" I get a dialog box with progress bar, and this dialog box disappears silently in a few seconds. No web page about search results displayed. I remember it was displaying some information previously.

What can prevent this searching from work?

My question is about this feature not about BSOD's.

Comment: Did you try using it on something besides BSODs..?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a very specific and relatively small set of errors where Microsoft has a solution that they will report back to you. I had a crash in Microsoft Word once, and after clicking Check for Solution it told me about an Office Service Pack that included a fix for that particular crash. But that's the only time I've seen a solution. All other times I see the progress bar and then nothing, just as you're seeing.